# Reading nothing from a pdf file using PyPDF2

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I want to convert a pdf file to json format. So I was using PyPDF2 module to read the pdf. But I am unable to read it. I gives me some "\n" characters but no text. The pdf I am using can be retrieve from here:
[pdf_to_json.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1omhnLccve4SvOUfTGjtK3r4nS56-0j8K/view?usp=sharing)

The code I am using is:

```
import PyPDF2

file = open("pdf_to_json.pdf", "rb")

pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)

page_one = pdf.getPage(0)

page_one.extractText()
```

It's returning something like this:

```
'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

DISCLAIMER: The pdf is in spanish

Comment: The PDF definitely has text content, it's not just a scanned document (just images), correct? Edit: sorry, just noticed you linked to the PDF

Comment: pyPDf2 is not a suitable library for extracting content from the table. try this method : https://medium.com/@winston.smith.spb/python-an-easy-way-to-extract-data-from-pdf-tables-c8de22308341

Comment: I also have successfully used pdfminer.six for this sort of task. Would recommend it, super easy to use too.

Comment: Yes, pdfminer.six is a magic! It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Zubayer, you handled your issue, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just update to the latest version of `pypdf`.

I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. We moved the project towards pypdf. It had tons of improvements in 2022, especially for text extraction.

### code

```
from  pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("pdf_to_json.pdf")
page_one = reader.pages[0]
print(page_one.extract_text())
```

### Result

```
Doe, JOHN
NIF/CIF:     12345678A
EMPRESA DOMICILIO Nº    INSCRIPCIÓN S.S.
JANE Doe Fiction Street, 13 12/3456789
TRABAJADOR CATEGORÍA PUESTO DE  TRABAJO ANTIGÜEDAD D.N.I.
JOHN Doe TRAMO   1 No   informado 01/01/20 21 12345678A
Nº  AFILIACIÓN  S.S. TARIFA EPIG. SECCIÓN NRO. PERIODO TOT. DÍAS
12/3456789 000001 01/01/2021    -
01/01/202130
CUANTÍA PRECIO CONCEPTO DEVENGOS DEDUCCIONES
72.00 5.76 1*SALARIO    BASE 355.63
72.00 0.82 2*PARTE  PROPOR. PAGAS   EXTRAS 59.27
Cotización  Contingencias   Comunes
(4.55%)17.62
REM.    TOTAL P.P.  EXTRAS BASE C.C. BASE   A.T.    Y   DES BASEI.R.P.F. T. DEVENGADO T. A  DEDUCIR
387.29 387.29 414.90 17.62
FECHA
Lunes,  01 de   diciembre   de   2000 
City NameSELLO  EMPRESA RECIBÍ
Líquido a   percibir
397.28
DETERMINACIÓN   DE  LAS BASES   DE  COTIZACIÓN  A   LA  S.S.    Y   CONCEPTOS   DE  RECAUDACIÓN CONJUNTA    Y   DE  LA  BASE    SUJETA  A   RETENCIÓN   DEL IRPF
Y   APORTACIÓN  DE  LA  EMPRESA
CONCEPTO BASE TIPO APORTACIÓN   EMPRESA
Contingencias   Comunes
Importe remuneración    mensual
Importe prorrata    pagas   extraordinarias
Base    Incapacidad Temporal 387.29 22.85% 88.50
Contingencias   Profesionales
AT  y   EP 387.29 1.10% 4.26
Desempleo 387.29
Formación   profesional 387.29
Fondo   de  garantía    salarial 387.29
Base    de  cotización  adicional   por horas
extraordinarias
Base    sujeta  a   retención   I.R.P.F.
```

Comment: Seems like pypdf fixed this bug.